# jQuery AJAX POST gives undefined index

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, post

My eventinfo.php is giving the following output:

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index:  club in <b>/homepages/19/d361310357/htdocs/guestvibe/wp-content/themes/yasmin/guestvibe/eventinfo.php</b> on line <b>11</b><br />
[]
```

HTML (index.php):

```
<select name="club" class="dropdown" id="club">
<?php getClubs(); ?>
</select>
```

jQuery (index.php):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://www.guestvibe.com/wp-content/themes/yasmin/guestvibe/eventinfo.php",
            data:  $('#club').serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                $('#rightbox_inside').html('<h2>' + $('#club').val() + '<span style="font-size: 14px"> (' + data[0].day + ')</h2><hr><p><b>Entry:</b> ' + data[0].entry + '</p><p><b>Queue jump:</b> ' + data[0].queuejump + '</p><br><p><i>Guestlist closes at ' + data[0].closing + '</i></p>');
                },
            dataType: "json"
        });
    });

    $('#club').change(function(event) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://www.guestvibe.com/wp-content/themes/yasmin/guestvibe/eventinfo.php",
            data:  $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                $('#rightbox_inside').hide().html('<h2>' + $('#club').val() + '<span style="font-size: 14px"> (' + data[0].day + ')</h2><hr><p><b>Entry:</b> ' + data[0].entry + '</p><p><b>Queue jump:</b> ' + data[0].queuejump + '</p><br><p><i>Guestlist closes at ' + data[0].closing + '</i></p>').fadeIn('500');
                },
            dataType: "json"
        });

    });

</script>
```

I can run alerts from the jQuery, so it is active.

I've copied this as is from an old version of the website, but I've changed the file structure (through to move to WordPress) so I suspect the variables might not even be reaching eventinfo.php in the first place...

index.php is in wp-content/themes/cambridge and eventinfo.php is in wp-content/themes/yasmin/guestvibe but I've tried to avoid structuring issues by referencing the URL in full.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Sorry, forgot about eventinfo.php. I suspect only really line 3 is relevant but I may be wrong.

```
include('functions.php');
connect();
$night = $_POST['club'];
$night = mysql_real_escape_string($night);

$query = "SELECT * FROM nights WHERE name = '" .$night. "'";

    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $items = array();

    if($result && mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
        $items[] = array("entry"=>$row['entry'], "day"=>getLongDateString($row['day']), "queuejump"=>$row['queue jump'], "closing"=>$row['closing']);
        }
    } 

    mysql_close(); 
    // convert into JSON format and print

    echo json_encode($items);
?>
```

vardump[$_POST] gives:

```
array(0) {
}
```

Comment: Looks like the error is occurring in code that you haven't posted here... Can you please post the ** relevant** code from your `eventinfo.php` file?

Comment: Is it not everything about eventinfo.php after all? Can you paste the code?

Comment: paste some code of your eventinfo.php where this notice generated.

Comment: can you paste var_dump($_POST) ?

Comment: i think you are not getting $_POST['club']. may be you change your jquery data line to data: "club="+$('#club').serialize(). var_dump($_POST) really help to debug this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your index.php file, you have this:

```
<select name="club" class="dropdown" id="club">
<?php getClubs(); ?>
</select>
```

Change this to **(updated)**:

```
<form name="myform" id="myform" action="submit.php" method="POST">
<select name="club" class="dropdown">
<?php getClubs(); ?>
</select>
</form>
```

Then change your code to `$('#myform').serialize()` instead of `$('#club').serialize()`

$_POST['club'] is null that's why you are getting the notice. It's null because it's not getting submitted properly. The form must be submitted, not the select element. The form itself must be `serialize()`, not the select element.

Comment: This gives all the same results as before. Could it be because that part of my php file is already within a larger form? `<form name="myform" action="submit.php" method="POST">`

Comment: yes, i updated my answer. you need to `.serialize()` the form.

Comment: I'm afraid that gives me the same result, also if I just wrap <form> around that part of the original form.

Comment: are you using Chrome? Check the developer tools and see what is being sent. Press Ctrl+Shift+J just before you submit, then go to Network. Click on the eventinfo.php file that was loaded and check in Headers what is being sent.

Comment: As I say, I've had this code working before, I've just moved it. Having said that, eventinfo.php down the left-hand side of the Developer Tools is in red...

Comment: even if it turns red, it's supposed to show you the headers and other request/response data. just click on it and the details will be loaded in the right

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.guestvibe.com/wp-content/themes/yasmin/guestvibe/eventinfo.php. Origin http://cambridge.guestvibe.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.` <-- there you go. They are on different domains. Try to install them on the same domain if possible. Otherwise, you can try to [override domain restriction](http://www.cypressnorth.com/blog/programming/cross-domain-ajax-request-with-json-response-for-iefirefoxchrome-safari-jquery/) by putting `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` on top of the PHP file.